# PHP & Ajax , Javascript - How to display modal when data is fetched into the database instead of text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How can I fetch the data and displayed it as a Modal Popup and not a Text,

and here comes the problem because this code

errors

[image]

database structure

[image]

`index.php`

```
    <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">


 ?>


</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "select.php", //create a php for the SELECT STATEMENT
        //data: $("#signin").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function (data) {
            $("#myModal").html(data);
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
    });

</script>
```

Here is the second page which is select.php 
here is where the modal will be fetched

`select.php`

```
<?php 

$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link, "autorefresh");

$res = mysqli_query($link,"select * from table1");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo '  <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>'.$row["name"]." ".$row["city"].'</p>
          </div>';
}
```

Comment: You don't show your html, but I'm guessing that your div with id `myModal` is empty, in which case changing its display property is not going to have much - if any - visible effect. You also need to insert the content of the Ajax response (which currently you're doing nothing with). You said this was working, what's not clear is what you want to do that the previous code was not doing.

Comment: @RobinZigmond yes it is working only in text but not in modal.. the modal is not showing

Comment: @RobinZigmond i need the modal to popup when i insert a data in the database .. but in my case it is not showing

Comment: Exactly what are you using for modals? Bootstrap?

Comment: no i just have css @JeanPaul98 that's where im displaying the modal

Comment: So your CSS and JS looks something like this? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: @JeanPaul98 exactly sir , you're on point :)

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want it so that the modal opens every time you insert data in to the DB? Or every time you run the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @JeanPaul98 hope you can help me sir, you are correct with all your question

Comment: @JeanPaul98 i want it to open every time i insert data in to the DB ! That's it sir !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186229/discussion-between-jeanpaul98-and-obito-uchiha).

Answer (score 0):

You did't define what `modal` is.... Try this lines,

```
success: function (data) {
            $("#myModal").html(data);
            $("#myModal").slideDown('slow');
        }
```

The line `$("#myModal").slideDown('slow');` will show your model with slideDown effect.
Also you can use `$("#myModal").css('display','block');` to display instead of the slideDown effect.

**MODAL POPUP**

To create a `modal popup` you need to use `bootstrap`.
add boostrap to your project then try this,

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**And in your `javascript`,**

```
success: function (data) {
                $("#myModal .modal-body").html(data);
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            }
```

The line `$("#myModal").modal('show');` will popup the modal.